# Not commuting operator calculation

Tags: operators, algebra

I am working on some operator calculation; I do not want the commutation relation.

so xy ≠ yx.

I found the mathematica code from

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html

and from the example code,

```
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
 Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
 Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]
ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]
```

so that

```
ExpandNCM[(a + b) ** (c + z)]
```

I got

```
a ** c + a ** z + b ** c + b ** z
```

But the problem is, it does not recognize the real number such that

```
ExpandNCM[2 (a + b) ** (c + z)]
2 (a + b) ** (c + z)
```

It will work if I make it like (Obviously)

```
2 * ExpandNCM[(a + b) ** (c + z)]
2 (a ** c + a ** z + b ** c + b ** z)
```

Would you help me to add some condition that if the variable is Real number, then take it out front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this done in the [NCAlgebra](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) package. The relevant pieces of code can be found in their `NCMultiplication.m` and are (roughly) these:

```
Literal[NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, NonCommutativeMultiply[b__], c___]] :=
    NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, c];
Literal[NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_ c_, d___]]:=
    b NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c, d] /; CommutativeAllQ[b]
Literal[NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_, c___]] :=
    b NonCommutativeMultiply[a, c] /; CommutativeAllQ[b]
Literal[NonCommutativeMultiply[a_]] := a;
NonCommutativeMultiply[] := 1;
```

where

```
CommutativeAllQ[x_Symbol] := CommutativeQ[x];
CommutativeAllQ[x_Integer] := True;
CommutativeAllQ[x_Real] := True;
CommutativeAllQ[x_String] := True;
CommutativeAllQ[c_?NumberQ] := True;
CommutativeAllQ[f_[x___]] := 
     If[CommutativeQ[f], Apply[And,Map[CommutativeAllQ,{x}]]
                       , False
     ];
```

where

```
CommutativeQ[x_Symbol] := True;
CommutativeQ[x_Integer] := True;
CommutativeQ[x_Real] := True;
CommutativeQ[x_String] := True;
If[Global`$NC$ForceCommutativeAllQ===True
  , CommutativeQ[x_] := CommutativeAllQ[x];
  , CommutativeQ[x_] := True;
];
```